# What does this C pointer error mean? Why is it happening this way

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *block = malloc(BYTE * 512);
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
     
    fclose(argv[1]);
}
```

I don't know how what am I doing wrong, I haven't started writing any actual code yet, I'm new to pointers in C. I'm already having errors without even having done anything, I am very sorry.

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    recover.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o recover
recover.c:9:26: error: unexpected type name 'BYTE': expected expression
    char *block = malloc(BYTE * 512);
                         ^
recover.c:12:12: error: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'FILE *' (aka 'struct _IO_FILE *') [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    fclose(argv[1]);
           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:213:26: note: passing argument to parameter '__stream' here
extern int fclose (FILE *__stream);
                         ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: recover] Error 1
```

Comment: `BYTE` is not a variable but a type, and the type of `argv[1]` is `char*` instead of `FILE*`.

Comment: Tell us in plain english what you think `malloc(BYTE * 512)` is doing.

Comment: You are asking _only_ about the "pointer error", but you have two errors (in three lines of code - good hit rate!).  Surely "`passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'FILE *`'" is pretty self explanatory?

Comment: Do the allocation like this: `block = malloc(sizeof *block * 512)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `fclose` you should pass a `FILE *` as parameter, for your case it will be `fclose(file);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a *type*, use the size of a type

```
//char *block = malloc(BYTE * 512);
char *block = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);
```

Even better, do not use a type at all.

```
char *block = malloc(sizeof *block * 512);
```

Comment: That's _one_ problem.

Comment: Thanks! used block[512] instead. Can you help me with the other error

Comment: Except then assigning to a `char*` rather then a `BYTE*` makes no sense - it is either a block of `BYTE` or a block of `char`.

Comment: @Clifford with `uint8_t` existing, size of `uint8_t, BYTE, char` are all one byte each.  `sizeof *block` avoids the "correct type" concern.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I appreciate that.  It was a point about the OP's code rather than your answer. It should have been applied to the question, Sory.  It may not matter in this case, but it is semantically flawed.  To go to the trouble of creating a type alias then not to use it consistently is a recipe for maintenance issues.